# Pass all class methods to another function in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have made the following validation method:

```
  def if_admin(&block)
       if @current_user.administrator?
           yield
       else
           redirect_to '/go_away'
       end
  end
```

and i find my classes are increasingly looking like:

```
class Foo < ApplicationsController

    def index
        if_admin do
              .....
        end
    end
    def show
        if_admin do
              .....
        end
    end
    def new
        if_admin do
              .....
        end
    end
    def edit
        if_admin do
              .....
        end
    end
    .......
end
```

I want to know if there is anything similar to before_action which would pass the method into the if_admin method, thus DRYing up the code?

Comment: Yes, there is `before_action`, literally. Why don't you use it?

Comment: is there a way to pass the parameter method into before action, then preventing the action repeating?

Comment: What do you mean by this? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You should use [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you wrote, there is [`before_action`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_action). You can use it like this:

```
class Foo < ApplicationsController
  before_action :if_admin
  # ...
  private
  def if_admin
    redirect_to '/go/away' unless @current_user.administrator?
  end
end
```

Comment: does the redirect prevent the execution of the rest of the method?

Comment: Yes, redirect in `before_action` prevents action itself from being called.